# How do I toggle paypal trial period subscription?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I want to toggle paypal trial period based on whether user had already a trial period or not.
I use `next.js` with `react-paypal-button-v2`

If one had trial then I don't want to set it in stripe but if he/she does not had one then I want to set it to true.

I have this flow:

1. User can sign in using facebook -> buy subscription using stripe -> he will get the trial period -> once the trial expires and his subscription as well he can buy one with paypal and here I want to toggle the trial period because if I don't do this my user will get the trial period when he already had one. I have an api call which checks whether user had subscription but I don't know how to disable trial period in paypal.

I have two options how to solve this issue:

1. To create a plan on every paypal button press and set trial period there if needed
2. Create new plans without trial period and toggle them. If user had no trial period then user plan_id with trial, if he had trial period -> user plan_id without trial period

Answer (score 0):

You can create all your plan_ids with a trial period, as this would seem to be the most common use case -- and then override the plan details when the trial is not being offered.

In the button code, next to the `plan_id`, you can actually specify a `plan` object with any overrides you want.

See the documentation with examples for creating a plan https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#plans_create , in particular they have a `billing_cycles` object where you would specify only one cycle without a trial for the override `plan`.

See the documentation for creating a subscription with that `plan` override: https://developer.paypal.com/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_create

So again, in addition to the `plan_id` you want an object named `plan` with a `billing_cycles` array with one item that is not a trial.